# Why does the tac with -s switch display output same as the cat?

Tags: linux, bash, gnu

When I use `tac -s=STRING filename`, it dumps the file in the original order - not reverse order - to the STDOUT? Why does it do so - when tac is supposed to reverse the order and with `-s=STRING` it should use STRING as the separator instead of the newline?

Comment: Does your input data contain `STRING` anywhere?

Answer (score 4):

When using the short option `-s` you must not use `=` between option and argument:

```
tac -s STRING filename
```

`=` is only valid when using the long option:

```
tac --separator=STRING filename
```